# How can I set a string and a double in the same TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I've been trying to put a double and a string in a textView on android studio, but everytime I try it ends up adding the string to the double like an adition, i tried putting comas instead of "+" but it marked error, maybe the answer it's pretty obvious but I haven found it till the momment this is what I have

[image]

Comment: Post your actual code instead of pictures of your code, take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The + operator adds two operands if both of them are numbers. It performs the concatenation only if at least one of them is `String`.

For example.

```
double a = 1.5;
double b = 2.5;
```

Now to to concatenate the above two numbers, you should use:

```
String result = ""+a+b;
//or String result = String.valueOf(a) + b;
textView.setText(result);
```

If you use `textView.setText(""+a+b)` you will get a warning related to localization. But your code will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate before you set the text:

```
String text = altura2 + AlturaPLUS;
textView.setText(text);
```